# Why do we have these values of the generalized character when evaluated with the scalar product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Let $U \le G$ be a subgroup of odd order of the finite group $G$. Suppose $t \notin U$ is an involution with $u^t \in uU'$ for all $u \in U$, where $U'$ denotes the commutator subgroup of $U$. Set $T := \langle t \rangle$. Let $\lambda \ne 1$ be a linear character of $U$ and extend it to linear character $\hat \lambda$ on $TU$ by setting $\hat \lambda(tu) = \hat \lambda(u) = \lambda(u)$ for all $u \in U$.

Set $S := TU \setminus T^U$. Then for $g \in G$ we have that $S^g \ne S$ implies $S^g \cap S = \emptyset$ and $N_G(S) = TU$, and the generalised character $1 - \hat \lambda$ is zero outside of $S$. Furthermore
$$
((1 - \hat\lambda), (1 - \hat\lambda))_{TU} = 2
$$
and
$$
 (1_{TU}, (1 - \hat \lambda))_{TU} = 1.
$$

As $u^{-1}t = u^{-1}tx$ with $x \in U'$ and $\lambda(x) = 1$ we have $\hat \lambda(u^{-1} t u) = \hat \lambda(tu^{-1}xu) = \lambda(u^{-1}xu) = 1$, hence $1 - \hat \lambda$ is zero outside of $S$.

> But why do we have 
>   $((1 - \hat\lambda), (1 - \hat\lambda))_{TU} = 2$ and $(1_{TU}, (1 - \hat \lambda))_{TU} = 1$?

Comment: Hi, what is $T$?

Comment: This seems clear from the linearity of the inner product. What's the problem?

Comment: @FrancisBegbie: $T = \langle t \rangle$ for the involution $t$, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is indeed simple by using orthogonality relations and $\lambda \ne 1$
$$
 ((1 - \hat\lambda), (1-\hat\lambda))_{TU}
  = (1,1)_{TU} - (1, \hat\lambda)_{TU} - (\hat\lambda, 1) + (\hat\lambda, \hat\lambda)_{TU}
 = 1 - 0 - 0 + 1 = 2
$$
and
$$
 (1_{TU}, (1 - \hat\lambda))_{TU}
  = (1_{TU}, 1_{TU})_{TU} - (1_{TU}, \hat\lambda)_{TU}
  = 1 - 0.
$$